# How to extract a value by name from "name value name value ..."-like input lines

Tags: awk

Consider a stream of lines piped to `awk`. Lines are composed of sequence of interleaved field names and field values, like the following example (lines really are much longer with many other attributes listed):

> Samples 2978 Min -0.068689 at 1389 Amin 1.0406e-08 at 435 Max 0.0514581 at 1375
>   Samples 2977 Min -0.100258 at 1293 Amin -1.06743e-08 at 3 Max 0.0989735 at 1282
>   Samples 2977 Min -0.109783 at 1281 Amin -2.97293e-08 at 10 Max 0.139651 at 1268
>   Samples 2976 Min -0.116509 at 1269 Amin -1.04306e-09 at 161 Max 0.0985577 at 1255

I'd like to extract a certain value from the strings using it's name as a guide, for example, `Min`. If I had a `scanf`-like function in `awk`, I'd have at first used `ind=index($0, "Min")`, then `s=substr($0, ind)`, then `sscanf(s,"Min %f", &val)` to obtain `val`. However, I dont have any `scanf` available in awk.

How can I extract the value by it's name then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You go through each field, check for "Min" and then extract the next field

```
$ awk '{for(o=1;o<=NF;o++) if ($o =="Min" ) {print $(o+1)} }' file
-0.068689
-0.100258
-0.109783
-0.116509
```

Ruby(1.9+)

```
$ ruby  -ne 'puts $_.scan(/Min\s+(.[^\s]*)/)' file
```

Answer (score 1):

\1. Can't you rely on data elements to be in the same column position in each record? Then you can simply say

```
awk '{print $3}' dataFile
```

To get the Min value per your example.

\2. Kurumi idea is fine.

\3. Here's another method that ensures you match data with its label

```
awk '{
     minVal=$0
     sub(/^.*Min /, "",minVal)
     sub(/ .*$/, "", minVal)
     printf minVal" "
     maxVal=$0
     sub(/^.*Max /, "",maxVal)
     sub(/ .*$/, "", maxVal)
     printf maxVal "\n"
   } '  dataFile
```

You can do the modifications directly on $0, but because awk "recalculates" the field values everytime $0 is edited, it will be (in my experience) a much slower process.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Since the value follows the name immediately, it would probably easier to find the first encounter of the `name`, cut the string from `$0` and assign back to `$0`. This way, the needed value is always at `$2`.

Answer (score 0):

This will scan field by field only those lines containing the label.

```
BEGIN {a="^Min$"}

/a/   {for(i = 1; i <= $NF; i++) { if (match($i,a)) print $i,$(i+1)}}
```

->

```
Min -0.068689
Min -0.100258
Min -0.109783
Min -0.116509
```

Running at [ideone](http://ideone.com/clone/CJKmq)